# JSXGraph. Calculate displacement of point

Tags: jsxgraph

How can i calculate displacement of a point in JSXGRAPH. Suppose there is a point A at (0, 0) location. If i drag point A from (0, 0) to (2, 0). the displacement is 2 units. My query is what is the formula in jsxgraph to calculate this displacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to calculate the distance between two JSXGraph points, say `p` and `q`, the `Dist` method can be used:

```
p.Dist(q)
```

If you want to determine the distance from point `p` to a coordinate array `[x, y]`, it is done like this:

```
JXG.Math.Geometry.distance(p.coords.usrCoords, [1, x, y]);
```

Instead of `[x, y]` one has to use `[1, x, y]`, because JSXGraph works with homogeneous coordinates, which allow to handle also infinite points.

A dynamic example would look like this:

```
var p = board.create('point', [3, 0]),
    q = board.create('point', [0, 0]),
    t = board.create('text', [1, 1, function() { return p.Dist(q); }]);
```